# WebRTC - JSEP: cannot connect peer between two different network

Tags: webrtc

I don't know if anybody have issued this, but I wan't to ask. My problem was like this:

- I could use video chatting from apprtc.appspot.com using two Chrome tab (which means I call myself). Everything worked well.
- I could use apprtc with two different laptop as well, if those laptop were on the same network. I used my university's network behind proxy.
- However, apprtc didn't work if I used it with one laptop on modem, and the other on LAN.

Can anybody explain what happened? Is this STUN/ICE problem? Or JSEP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been able to use the demo at http://apprtc.appspot.com/ from behind two different NAT's. So it can at least work in theory; but it's also fairly well known that STUN, TURN and ICE aren't infallible. For starters, if someone has blocked access to the port 19302 (the port of the STUN server that the apprtc demo uses), the firewall traversal will never be able to get started.

The basic troubleshooting step would be to open up the Chrome developer tools (ctrl-shift-i) and look to see if there are any errors in the console. Failing to observe anything interesting there, you'd need to write up your own version of the demo app, this time with better error handling. For instance, the apprtc demo assumes certain things that can't really be taken for granted, for instance, that `peerConnection.setLocalDescripton()` and `peerConnection.setRemoteDescription()` will succeed. In production code, you'd really need to implement both success and failure callbacks on those - and that would give you better information about what might be going wrong.

Comment: If you're sitting behind a typical consumer home router, that's where your firewall (such as it is) is located. But what does the console log show?

Comment: i see the candidate message with address data filled with my private IP, and I just tested with telnet to stun.l.google.com with port 19302 but it couldn't connect

Comment: You might want to try it with a different stun server. Can you access any of those on this list? http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/STUN

Comment: i tried this stun.stunprotocol.org and it get connected with the server, but my webrtc still cannot connect different network. sometimes peerconnection can get the public ip, sometimes it can't, so the candidate data have different ip

Answer (score 5):

The public demo includes a STUN server but does not provide a TURN sever because the bandwidth to run a free TURN server is expensive. STUN get thought lots but not all NATs / firewalls but not anywhere near as many as TURN. You might be in a situation where TURN would work (but you don't have a TURN server) but STUN does not.

Answer (score 3):

AppRTC uses stun by default. TURN is 'better' (from my understanding), but I recall Justin Uberti saying public TURN servers will likely be misused (or something to that effect).

STUN often fails on enterprise grade subnets because it can't 'cope' with unfriendly NAT addressing.